# Solidity and multiple inheritance

Tags: solidity, inheritance

I'm attempting to understand how solidity resolves multiple inheritance. As explained [in the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#multiple-inheritance-and-linearization), Solidity uses [C3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization). The relation between my classes is displayed on the image below:
[image: Inheritance graph]

I want to understand in which order `super` is working when called from `SampleCrowdsale`. I ran the C3 linearization algorithm manually as well as using [this](https://github.com/federicobond/c3-linearization) tool. The results I get:

```
1) SampleCrowdsale
2) CappedCrowdsale
3) RefundableCrowdsale
4) FinalizableCrowdsale
5) TimedCrowdsale
6) MintedCrowdsale
7) IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale
8) TieredCrowdsale
9) Crowdsale
10) Ownable
```

Then I tried to confirm my findings empirically. I added a method `log` to every contract in the inheritance chain, the method fires an event with the contract name. My findings using this method differ from the analytical approach:

```
1) SampleCrowdsale
2) TieredCrowdsale
3) IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale
4) MintedCrowdsale
5) RefundableCrowdsale
6) FinalizableCrowdsale
7) TimedCrowdsale
8) CappedCrowdsale
9) Crowdsale
10) Ownable
```

Can anyone explain to me how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a few test and seems like the order you use to extend the classes it matter. Given this example:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract Ownable {
    event OwnableE(uint);
    function Ownable() public {
        emit OwnableE(1);
    }
}
contract TimedCrowdsale {
    event TimedCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function TimedCrowdsale() public {
        emit TimedCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
contract Crowdsale {
    event CrowdsaleE(uint);
    function Crowdsale() public {
        emit CrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}

contract FinalizableCrowdsale is Ownable, TimedCrowdsale  {
    event FinalizableCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function FinalizableCrowdsale() public {
        emit FinalizableCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
    event CappedCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function CappedCrowdsale() public {
        emit CappedCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
} 
contract RefundableCrowdsale is FinalizableCrowdsale {
    event RefundableCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function RefundableCrowdsale() public {
        emit RefundableCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
contract MintedCrowdsale is Crowdsale { 
    event MintedCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function MintedCrowdsale() public {
        emit MintedCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
contract IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale is Ownable, Crowdsale { 
    event IndividuallyCappedCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale() public {
        emit IndividuallyCappedCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
contract TieredCrowdsale is Ownable, Crowdsale {
    event TieredCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function TieredCrowdsale() public {
        emit TieredCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}

contract SampleCrowdsale is CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale, TieredCrowdsale { 
    event SampleCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function SampleCrowdsale() public {
        emit SampleCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
```

the call chain would be:

```
[
    {
        "topic": "bdac561e97cd2f10f81e3ccfa6953563ea5921aacbbed1a01338388b58b7035b",
        "event": "OwnableE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "0745b765421933707f4bdaebed6f1478ed78c6f1fa656035d672a1eb04a914ce",
        "event": "CrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "7e78dc6ab4bed05d0901d10704f58ce946a5eb50d3a279d26887df13fe4b19d6",
        "event": "CappedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "896ac1cf1e4f0dea962c7533989a352036679bd5222c53e344f88a80eb70febb",
        "event": "TimedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "07b3016f470d5b16960d54a55cb7e9bd74c20746a19c7cb0ba634a52e83934ce",
        "event": "FinalizableCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "2a1ec31b0b7f73e6938c981b1f806a9d76ec0c1904a53de98197f2b7054301d7",
        "event": "RefundableCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "39a8041bef698db3de246b679ad52b01b9f8ba609de0573804701617faac2803",
        "event": "MintedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "9dde5892f2ad9eb0f156963773cf38cad6b804f8061d765fbbbc10f9d3d4048f",
        "event": "IndividuallyCappedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "3171f924f0e542de51df919c69da5e54fb7c51a9467384a87261ac7f6f945f48",
        "event": "TieredCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "615ecfd72872a19eeed214c27309877c89602943fa4b789f87d67fc0cce30a11",
        "event": "SampleCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    }
]
```

from the bottom to the top this would be the order

```
SampleCrowdsale
TieredCrowdsale
IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale
MintedCrowdsale
RefundableCrowdsale
FinalizableCrowdsale
TimedCrowdsale
CappedCrowdsale
Crowdsale
Ownable
```

same as the one you found on your empirical approach.

But if I change the order of the class that I'm going to extend in the `SampleCrowdsale` the output would be different

```
contract SampleCrowdsale is TieredCrowdsale, IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale { 
    event SampleCrowdsaleE(uint);
    function SampleCrowdsale() public {
        emit SampleCrowdsaleE(1);
    }
}
```

this will give you this output

```
[
    {
        "topic": "bdac561e97cd2f10f81e3ccfa6953563ea5921aacbbed1a01338388b58b7035b",
        "event": "OwnableE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "0745b765421933707f4bdaebed6f1478ed78c6f1fa656035d672a1eb04a914ce",
        "event": "CrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "3171f924f0e542de51df919c69da5e54fb7c51a9467384a87261ac7f6f945f48",
        "event": "TieredCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "9dde5892f2ad9eb0f156963773cf38cad6b804f8061d765fbbbc10f9d3d4048f",
        "event": "IndividuallyCappedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "39a8041bef698db3de246b679ad52b01b9f8ba609de0573804701617faac2803",
        "event": "MintedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "896ac1cf1e4f0dea962c7533989a352036679bd5222c53e344f88a80eb70febb",
        "event": "TimedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "07b3016f470d5b16960d54a55cb7e9bd74c20746a19c7cb0ba634a52e83934ce",
        "event": "FinalizableCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "2a1ec31b0b7f73e6938c981b1f806a9d76ec0c1904a53de98197f2b7054301d7",
        "event": "RefundableCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "7e78dc6ab4bed05d0901d10704f58ce946a5eb50d3a279d26887df13fe4b19d6",
        "event": "CappedCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "topic": "615ecfd72872a19eeed214c27309877c89602943fa4b789f87d67fc0cce30a11",
        "event": "SampleCrowdsaleE",
        "args": [
            "1"
        ]
    }
]
```

and the order is the one you expect (again from the bottom to the top on the logs)

```
SampleCrowdsale
CappedCrowdsale
RefundableCrowdsale
FinalizableCrowdsale
TimedCrowdsale
MintedCrowdsale
IndividuallyCappedCrowdsale
TieredCrowdsale
Crowdsale
Ownable
```

The linearization in Solidity is from the right to the left instead of left to right [as per wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) (used in Python). As the documentation states:

> Solidity is similar to Python in that it uses “C3 Linearization” to
>   force a specific order in the DAG of base classes.
>   Especially, the order in which the base classes are given in the is
>   directive is important: You have to list the direct base contracts in
>   the order from “most base-like” to “most derived”. Note that this
>   order is different from the one used in Python. In the following code,
>   Solidity will give the error “Linearization of inheritance graph
>   impossible”.

My overall consideration is to make it as simple as possible to avoid that the multiple inheritance will be a pain and you encounter the [yo-yo problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_problem).

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you. I also opened an issue on [github](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3856#issuecomment-380474860) and am waiting for the developers feedback

Comment: The issue has been resolved on the provided github issue. Could you update your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: The _issue_ is not resolved (provided is an issue anyway, I think is more the design of the language design), they just updated the documentation. As I wrote in my post, `the linearization in Solidity is from the right to the left instead of left to right as per wiki`. How should I updated the answer? I can't see any improvement to my answer in the github link.

Comment: The wiki has been updated and now is stating that linearization is being done from right to left. The way your conclusions are presented is that you state that you are unsure, however you were right. Could you update the conclusion with these details?

Comment: oh, got it. Now is more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be as formal as you would like, but it may be helpful.

Your diagram confuses me and I don't think it's what you want. It's more likely that you want `Ownable` to be inherited by `SampleCrowdsale` and then various branches of increasing specialization.

```
contract Ownable {
    address public owner = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c; 

    function getOwner() public view returns(address theOwner) {
        return owner;
    }
}

contract SampleCrowdsale is Ownable {

    address public owner = 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c; 

    /**
     * super does not work in this context unless SampleCrowdsale is Ownable
     */

    function getOwner2() public view returns(address theOwner) {
        return super.getOwner();
    }
}

contract CappedCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {

    address public owner = 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db;

    /**
     * In this context, it comes from SampleCrowdsale
     */

    function getOwner3() public view returns(address anotherOwner) {
        return super.getOwner2(); // <== this would not work unless "super" referred to the (first, left to right) contract mentioned after "is".
    }

    /**
     * It's worth noting that inherited functions are now part of CappedCrowdsale
     * You can inspect (this) getOwner2() as well as (this) getOwner() because they
     * have become part of the CappedCrowdsale contract.
     * 
     * The following works because the function became part of SampleCrowdsale.
     */

    function telling() public view returns(address chained) {
        return super.getOwner();
    }
}
contract RefundableCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract MintedCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract TieredCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}

contract FinalizedCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale {}
contract TimedCrowdsale is FinalizedCrowdsale {}
```

The following is not exactly like your diagram. I think it's more aligned with what you're trying to achieve. I can't easily conceive of a Crowdsale that wouldn't be Ownable, and the rest seem to be specializations, so I'd probably get that concern out of the way first.

```
contract Ownable {}
contract Crowdsale is Ownable {}
contract SampleCrowdsale is Crowdsale {}
contract CappedCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract RefundableCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract MintedCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract TieredCrowdsale is SampleCrowdsale {}
contract FinalizedCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale {}
contract TimedCrowdsale is FinalizedCrowdsale {}
```

Everything is Ownable.

Since everything inherits the functions of Ownable, you can probably get by without using the `super` idea in most cases.

Or, if I take even more liberty, another interpretation is you want to create classes based on a basic Crowdsale and then present an Instance of one those classes as an example, called SampleCrowdsale. It might look something like this:

Define the re-usable classes

```
contract Ownable {}
contract Crowdsale is Ownable {}
contract CappedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {}
contract RefundableCrowdsale is Crowdsale {}
contract MintedCrowdsale is Crowdsale {}
contract TieredCrowdsale is Crowdsale {}
contract FinalizedCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale {}
contract TimedCrowdsale is RefundableCrowdsale {}
```

Then use one of them

```
contract SampleCrowdsale is TimedCrowdsale {}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If my answer gives you any ideas that lead to rethinking the original diagram, it might help others with the same quandary if you appended the revised version to the original question. It might really help others if they can see the evolution of your thinking.

Comment: but in his example `CappedCrowdsale`, `MintedCrowdsale`, `Crowdsale` and `TimedCrowdsale` are not ownable

Comment: I couldn't make it work as diagramed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but pragmatics aside, in the scope of this question I'm only interested in inheritance resolution. I think the pragmatics can be a separate question and would like to keep this focused.